# In Sitecore 7.5 is there a way to view a user's profile key values?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-dms, sitecore7.5, sitecore-xdb

In Sitecore 7.5 I have created a test campaign.  I have also created a test engagement plan.  I set up the campaign to automatically enroll users in the initial state of my engagement plan.  Then in my engagement plan I have a condition that checks for the value of a specific profile key.  I am doing some local testing with test users and I cannot seem to figure out if there is any way for me to view a user's stored profile key values.  Does this exist in Sitecore 7.5?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, exactly. Do you want to see these values in the database? In that case, you can find them in the `Interactions` collection in MongoDB.

Comment: Ideally I would like to be able to go to an interface in Sitecore somewhere where I could click on a user and then view their values for all of the different profile keys.  I can't seem to find any way that I can do that.

Comment: This is possible (starting from Sitecore 8.0, if I remember correctly). You can see a contact's profile card in a Sitecore app called Experience Profile.

Comment: Ok thanks. That's terrible in Sitecore 7.5 to not have that ability.  It makes using the DMS really, really difficult.  We are trying to set up engagement plans with conditions based on profile key values.  It is virtually impossible to troubleshoot and test because you really have no idea if the profile key values are accumulating properly for your users.  In fact, troubleshooting the engagement plans is really, really hard.

Comment: Well, you can always see profile key values directly in the database if you can't see them anywhere else.

Comment: But only in Mongo - right?  There is nothing in the SQL server Analytics DB - right?

Comment: Not after Sitecore 7.2.

Comment: Ok.  I can't really figure out where in Mongo I can go that will tell me how many points a user has accumulated for a particular profile key.  I see the Interactions collection in Mongo.  But that just seems to be individual records for a visit or interaction.

Comment: Well, a user collects points during a visit, and then these points are saved in MongoDB –> `Interactions`. Once a new visit starts, profiling starts from scratch. So every interaction/visit will have different profile key values.

Comment: Really?  I was under the impression that profile key values are built up over all visits and are saved to the user's profile.  So if a user collected 10 profile key points on visit 1 and 8 profile key points on visit 2 - then they would have 18 profile key points stored in their profile.  Is that not how it works?

Comment: Not as far as I know, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Experience Profile Application in Sitecore 7.5, it is on the Launch Pad, On the login screen choose User Interface: Launch Pad.
Or use this url to `/sitecore/shell/sitecore/Client/Applications/Launch Pad`

In the Sitecore Experience Profile you can find contacts and see the profile.

The following blog is about adding custom tab with custom profile keys.
http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2014/09/using-custom-contact-data-part-1-experience-profile.aspx you need it if your desired key is not there.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I never knew that was there before. Now I have to figure out why the Experience Profile app shows nothing in it.  I have no contacts in there at all even though I have tons of users and activity on my site.